# Redirect non-www on a Wordpress site without using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, seo

A developer that I worked with told me that we had the non-www version of the site redirecting to the www version using a Wordpress database setting, not the .htaccess file. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you try to access a WordPress site using anything other than the site address set in the general settings tab (Go to the admin panel, and click on "Settings" then "General settings" in the left side menu) it will automatically redirect you.

Comment: We already have the www version set in the general settings but it still doesn't redirect when someone goes to the non-www verson

Comment: It should be enabled by default in any recent version of WordPress... the feature was added in 2.4 or so.  In fact turning it off requires jumping through extra hoops: http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/turn-off-wordpress-homepage-url-redirection/   Maybe search through your wordpress directory for "redirect_canonical" in case some theme or plugin you've got installed does have it disabled?

Comment: Turns out it was an issue relating to the way our hosting company backed up and re-instated our database. Thanks Vinay.

Comment: www.example.com and example.com are seen as two different domains. Some web hosts, such as DreamHost, offer you a choice: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215457387-How-do-I-add-or-remove-www-from-my-domain-

Answer (score 1):

If you need non www pages  / posts to redirect www url in simple way then follow this steps.

1. login in to your **admin** panel
2. go to **settings options** in left side bottom
3. select  **General Settings**
4. add **" WWW " in the begaining** of both below fields.
      **WordPress Address (URL)**
      **Site Address (URL)**
5. save and login again. You are done now.

Best Regards.